# What is the symbolism of peacock?

Tags: analysis, laung-laachi

In *Laung Laachi*, Lacchi was shown doing village wall art and the specific focus was given to peacock.

Similarly after getting fame and money she was shown doing painting again and it was again peacock.

Is there any significance of drawing peacock respective to Laachi?